# Area of $r=e^{2\theta}$

Tags: calculus, integration, area

How to find area swept out by:
$$r=e^{2\theta},$$

looking in polar coordinate between $\theta=0$ and $\theta=\pi/2$?

I write in $x,y$ space as:
$$f(t) =(x(t),y(t))= e^{2t}(\cos(t),\sin(t)),$$
then area between two point $f(0)$ and $f(\pi/2)$ is given by 
$$\int_0^{\pi/2} |x'(t)y(t)-y'(t)x(t)|dt$$

and after expanding that out.  I get $\frac{e^{2\pi}-1}{4}$, is this right? Can someone verify.

Is this right area? it calculate to $133$, and I think intuitively since this fits in the upper right quarter of a circle, it should be less than a fourth of a circle of radius $e^{2\pi}$, and since it expands outwards, I'd say less than an 8th sounds okay, which is $210$, so maybe it is okay?

Comment: why don't you use $$A=\frac{1}{2}\int_a^b(f(\theta))^2d\theta$$?

Comment: I think that you are missing a factor $1/2$. Compare with [Green's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_theorem#Area_calculation). The path integral $$\dfrac12\int x\,dy-y\,dx$$ automatically vanishes on radial lines, so you can ignore the parts of the borders on the $x$ and $y$ axes.

Answer (score 1):

In the complex plane,

$$
z=e^{(2+i)\theta}=re^{i\theta}\\
\begin{align}
A
&=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\pi/2}\mathfrak{Im}\{z^*\dot z\}~d\theta\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\pi/2}\mathfrak{Im}\{re^{-i\theta}[(ir+\dot r)]e^{i\theta}\}~d\theta\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\pi/2}r^2~d\theta=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\pi/2}e^{4\theta}~d\theta\\
&=\frac{e^{2\pi}-1}{8}
\end{align}
$$

Incidentally, this is a logarithmic spiral with a *huge* flair coefficient.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: after the formula above we get $$A=\frac{e^{2\pi}-1}{8}$$

Comment: How is this a hint?